# NAudio Mp3 to WaveIn

Tags: vb.net, naudio

I wan to be able to output custom sounds mp3's to applications like chatroulette. I can either do that be a 'virtual microphone' and then select it in chatroulette (like an iso is an virtual cd drive). Or by outputting the mp3 to the wave in with NAudio.

This doesn't seem to work (as in DOES compile, DOES Excecute, but the recorder doesnt show any sounds).

```
 Dim DSO As New DirectSoundOut(DirectSoundOut.DSDEVID_DefaultCapture)
    Dim mp3 As WaveStream = New Mp3FileReader("D:\Muziek\Irish rebel songs\Athenrye - The armagh sniper.mp3")
    DSO.Init(mp3)
    DSO.Play()
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** Sorry, misunderstood what you were trying to do. Unfortunately, you can't play into a capture device using DirectSound.

Comment: no it doesn't exit, since it is tied to a gui thread, furthermore setting DSO parameter to the standardplayback, it does paly the music. But i dont want that i want that the microphone 'hears' it

Comment: is there any way I can send audio to a recording device (with or without directsound)?